# Can I use pip to install project from git with its dependency?

Tags: python, git, pip

So I have a package that have a set of dependencies which I list in requirements.txt. Some of this dependencies (our projects in git) have dependencies also listed in requirements.txt also.

Will pip install dependencies recursively somehow?

Comment: Show your requirements.txt lines and elaborate.  Do you have a project in git that also has a requirements.txt and you want pip to find that file?

Comment: If they're *only* in `requirements.txt`, then no: you will have to manually `pip install -r requirements.txt` once you've installed the package. If they're *also* in `setup.py`, they will be installed by `pip install ...`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the package specifies what its requirements are in the setup.py file (see the [setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#requirement-objects) for details) then yes, it should install the dependencies recursively.

See [Requirements Specifiers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirement-specifiers) in the pip documentation.

> pip supports installing from “requirement specifiers” as implemented in pkg_resources Requirements

Comment: Okay, suppose its so. What if in setup.py there is an import of Cython?

Comment: Then your setup.py file is broken. You can't assume that anything non-standard is installed in your setup file.

Comment: At least you can't assume it unless you're in a function that is called after the requirements have been installed. There certainly shouldn't be a top level import of Cython.